# Printing an Array List

Tags: java, arraylist, printing

I need to print the values from an array list that I am reading in from a text file. This does not work, please help me understand why and suggest a possible fix.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("gravityVals.txt"));
ArrayList <Double> gravity = new ArrayList<Double>();
while(in.hasNextDouble())
{
  gravity.add(in.nextDouble());
}
in.close();
for (double i = 0; i < gravity.size(); i++)
{
  System.out.println(gravity[i]);
}
```

Comment: Since its a list not an array you need to use gravity.get(i)... and please make the i a int not a double...

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop change the double to an int and use the ArrayList get() method, ie:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < gravity.size(); i++){

   // Specify Index value to help with your logging 
   System.out.println("Value at index " + i + " is " + gravity.get(i));

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an expansion on @Petter Friberg's comment.
You need to make your loop counter (i) an int, not a double. Also, since gravity is an ArrayList and not an array, you need to use the method get to access each element in ArrayList.

```
for (int i = 0; i < gravity.size(); i++)
{
  System.out.println(gravity.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems with your code here that will cause it not to even compile.

1. You cannot access the elements of gravity with the [] operator.  You need to do gravity.get(i).
2. i needs to be a int not a double.

Otherwise the code you have will compile.  Whether it will work as you expect depends on the format of gravityVals.txt.  When you do not specify the delimiter to Scanner it uses the default which is simply whitespace.

Also just some general style guidelines assuming you are using Java 7+.

1. You do not need to specify the generic type "Double" when you declare "new ArrayList()"  The compiler will infer the type.
   `ArrayList<Double> gravity = new ArrayList<>()` will work just fine.
2. You should make use of the try-with-resources with Scanner.
   https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html
3. Make use of java's for-each syntax for the for loop.
   http://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-foreach-examples/

The following is much better.

```
List<Double> gravity = new ArrayList<>();
try(Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("gravityVals.txt"));) {
  while(in.hasNextDouble()) {
    gravity.add(in.nextDouble());
  }
}

for (Double val : gravity){
  System.out.println(val);
}
```